# Some problems solving an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given $$y'=\frac{e^{-y^2}}{y(2x+x^2)}$$

What is the best method to solve this equation? I thought write it in seperable notation, obtaining $$ \frac{X_1(x)}{X_2(x)}+\frac{Y_2(y)}{Y_1(y)}y'=0,$$ which has a solution $$\int\frac{X_1(x)}{X_2(x)}dx+\int\frac{Y_2(y)}{Y_1(y)}dy=c$$ I defined $$X_1=1; \quad X_2=2x+x^2; \quad Y_2=-y; \quad Y_1= e^{y^2}.$$ My solution is $$\frac 1 2 \log(x)-\log(x+2) -\frac 1 2 e^{y^2}=c.$$ Is this the correct solution?

Comment: You've made a mistake. $$
\begin{align} Y_2&=-y\exp(y^2) \\ Y_1&=1
\end{align}
$$

Comment: If you take the derivative of your solution, do you get what you started with? In other words, you can always test your solution. You've made an error in your answer.

Comment: How can I test it if it is in implicit form?

Comment: @Hempo: implicit differentiation, for example: http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/implicitdiffdirectory/ImplicitDiff.html

Comment: Seems to me the $1/2$ should apply to both of the logarithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $y'=\frac{e^{-y^2}}{y(2x+x^2)}$, which is separable, confirming your comment.

If we separate we have:

$$\int ye^{y^2}dy=\int\frac{1}{2x+x^2}dx$$

For $dy$ you can use the method of substitution and for $dx$ you can factor out an $x$ out of the denominator and use partial fractions.

Comment: I get $$\frac 1 2 (log(x) -log(x+2))- \frac 1 2 e^{y^2}=c$$. This implicit solution is the only way to write it? I get a very strange solution if I solve it for y (+- square root of ln(ln(...)etc

Comment: Hempo, you are correct on your integrate. I doubt your instructor would want you to simply it more because when I had these types of problems the instructor told me to leave as is because it will be too complex to simplify it using elementary functions. You are correct though.

Comment: great, tyvm for helping me